# Saving an image form clj-http request to file

Tags: clojure

I am trying to save a file downloaded using [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/)

I have the following code:

```
(def test-file
  (cl/get "http://placehold.it/350x150"))

(defn write-file []
   (with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer  "test-file.gif" :append true)]
(.write w (:body test-file))))
```

and when I try to make it as a byte-array, I get an exception:

```
       user=>     (def test-file
                    (cl/get "http://placehold.it/350x150" {:as :byte-array}))
       #'user/test-file
       user=> (write-file)
       IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: write for class java.io.BufferedWriter  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)
```

Help!

Comment: Though you can use clj-http, this can be done purely with clojure.java.io: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15628682/425313

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use binary output.

```
(def test-file
  (client/get "http://placehold.it/350x150" {:as :byte-array}))

(defn write-file []
   (with-open [w (java.io.BufferedOutputStream. (java.io.FileOutputStream. "test-file.gif"))]
     (.write w (:body test-file))))
```

**Edit:**
output-stream is better:

```
(defn write-file []
   (with-open [w (clojure.java.io/output-stream "test-file.gif")]
     (.write w (:body test-file))))
```

**Update:**

a elegant way:

```
(clojure.java.io/copy
 (:body (client/get "http://placehold.it/350x150" {:as :stream}))
 (java.io.File. "test-file.gif"))
```

Comment: More to the point, writer.write expects char[] and outputstream.write expects byte[]

Comment: But you should probably use clojure.java.io/output-stream