# In Clojure, how do you download an image from the web and save it to your file system?

Tags: clojure

How do you download an image from the web and save it to your file system using Clojure? I know the image url and I'm aware that I can't use `spit` and `slurp` to do this because it's binary data, not text.

I'd like to do this as simply as possible, ideally like how spit and slurp work. That is, without a lot of extra lines using buffers or byte arrays. I want to close the streams when I'm done, but I don't care if it's inefficient.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321264/saving-an-image-form-clj-http-request-to-file). Answered via IRC.

Comment: I'm going to leave this here so that google can find this better.  I did a google search first and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Though in practice the solutions to these two questions are nearly identical, this question is more general in that it doesn't involve `clj-http` to get the file. Therefore I don't think it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Zhitong He [pointed](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clojure/12afsy2cx1/simple-way-to-get-image-from-url#20121016fapmb64hnegin6cgb3lbi372a4) me to [this solution](http://users.utu.fi/machra/posts/2011-08-24-2-reddit-clojure.html), which worked best for my purposes:

```
 (defn copy [uri file]
  (with-open [in (io/input-stream uri)
              out (io/output-stream file)]
    (io/copy in out)))
```

As Zhitong notes, you'll need `(:require [clojure.java.io :as io])` in your namespace to use this as coded. Alternatively, you could refer to clojure.java.io directly:

```
(defn copy-uri-to-file [uri file]
  (with-open [in (clojure.java.io/input-stream uri)
              out (clojure.java.io/output-stream file)]
    (clojure.java.io/copy in out)))
```