# Clojure spit behaviour on byte arrays

Tags: file, clojure

The following code :

```
(spit "/Users/nha/tmp/spit.txt" (.getBytes "hello"))
```

produces a file containing "[B@71e054bc", which is independent of the content ("hello" in this case) since this is the [JVM representation of the address of a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address).

However the following works (taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321748/1327651)):

```
  (clojure.java.io/copy
   (.getBytes "hello")
   (java.io.File. "/Users/nha/tmp/spit.txt"))
```

And the file then contains the correct content "hello".

Why does `spit` behave like this ?  Is there a way to expand it's behaviour for bytes ?

Comment: You could just wrap the bytes in a string, `(spit "spit.txt" (String. (.getBytes "hello")))`? Difficult to see what use that would be, especially since raw bytes don’t have an encoding and the output will depend on the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem isn’t particular to byte arrays.

```
(spit "spit.txt" (Object.))
(slurp "spit.txt")              ;; => "java.lang.Object@90b293d"
```

Looking at the [source of `spit`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6668-L6674) you’ll see that it simply tries to obtain the string representation of the argument before writing it out.

You could try to wrap any byte array in a new string before writing, but take care to select the proper encoding.

```
;; platform-dependent!
(spit "spit.txt" (String. b))

;; better
(spit "spit.txt" (String. b java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets/UTF_8))
```

Answer (score 3):

the reason is that the **content** is passed to `str`

you can check that via `(source spit)`:

```
user=> (source spit)
(defn spit
  "Opposite of slurp.  Opens f with writer, writes content, then
  closes f. Options passed to clojure.java.io/writer."
  {:added "1.2"}
  [f content & options]
  (with-open [^java.io.Writer w (apply jio/writer f options)]
    (.write w (str content))))
;            - ^^^ - here
```

therefor you get the string representation of the byte-array written

EDIT: and since `spit` the "inverse" of `slurp` which gives you a string, it makes sense and is consistent behaviour